# checkout in spree3 application on heroku not working, can't find error in logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, stripe-payments, spree

I am having trouble in my heroku deployment of a spree3 application. Whenever I click the checkout button I am getting an error. I configured the application to use the Stripe Gateway on the Admin Payments Section.

I have spent all day looking for an answer but I haven't been able to find anything. Checkout works in development but not in production.

Also, everything else seems to work in production environment except checkout.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.1'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem 'rmagick', '2.14.0'

gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.61.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

gem 'spree', '3.0.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

These are my different logs:

heroku logs:

```
$ heroku logs
Your version of git is 1.9.4.. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375583+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375587+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375550+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/r
enderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375560+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/r
endering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375568+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375579+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_reco
rd/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375565+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_cont
roller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375577+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375580+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375593+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375474+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/deface-1.0.1/lib/deface/action_vie
w_extensions.rb:41:in `render'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375477+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/r
enderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375480+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375489+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/r
enderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375526+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/t
emplate.rb:333:in `instrument'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375531+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/r
enderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375533+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/r
enderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375557+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/r
endering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375595+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375597+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375600+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375606+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375627+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375588+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_cont
roller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375607+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375634+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375641+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375672+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375674+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375599+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375633+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/r
endering.rb:30:in `process'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375592+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375629+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_reco
rd/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375679+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375575+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375590+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375609+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375636+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375643+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375646+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375602+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375604+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_cont
roller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375612+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375638+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375664+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   ven
dor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375666+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb
:518:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375668+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.r
b:194:in `public_send'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375670+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.r
b:194:in `method_missing'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375685+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb
:34:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375611+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375614+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375681+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb
:35:in `block in call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375688+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/conditionalget
.rb:25:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375695+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/session/abstra
ct/id.rb:225:in `context'
2015-04-04T03:28:59.375631+00:00 app[we
b.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375645+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375648+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375676+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375677+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375683+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb
:34:in `catch'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375687+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in
`call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375690+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in
`call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375692+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375693+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375697+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/session/abstra
ct/id.rb:220:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375709+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375698+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375702+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_reco
rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375704+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375707+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375711+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375716+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375700+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_reco
rd/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375721+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375726+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375705+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375720+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375729+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375738+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375718+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375723+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logg
er.rb:38:in `call_app'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375725+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logg
er.rb:20:in `block in call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375741+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:11
3:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375736+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:
in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375728+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
port/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride
.rb:22:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375753+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `ru
n'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375731+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logg
er.rb:20:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375732+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375739+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
ch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375746+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in
`call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375756+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375758+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
2015-04-04T03:28:59.375743+00:00 ap
←[36mp[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375748+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/content_length
.rb:15:in `call'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375750+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webric
k.rb:89:in `service'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375751+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `s
ervice'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375755+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block
 in start_thread'
←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375745+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/applicati
on.rb:164:in `call'
←[33m2015-04-04T03:29:00.071318+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.usalightingsys
tems.com request_id=0cd59b84-cc93-470c-baec-30bce5ee33a4 fwd="107.130.121.83" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=
304 bytes=133
```

Some(they were too long so took out a bit of them) Heroku logs from app:

```
    $ heroku logs --source app
    Your version of git is 1.9.4.. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
    More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375583+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
    ller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
.....
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375612+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375638+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
    ller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375664+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375666+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb
    :518:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375668+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.r
    b:194:in `public_send'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375670+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.r
    b:194:in `method_missing'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375685+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb
    :34:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375611+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375614+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_contro
    ller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375681+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb
    :35:in `block in call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375688+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/conditionalget
    .rb:25:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375695+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/session/abstra
    ct/id.rb:225:in `context'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375631+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_cont
    roller/base.rb:137:in `process'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375645+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375648+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375676+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375677+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375683+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb
    :34:in `catch'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375687+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in
    `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375690+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in
    `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375692+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375693+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375697+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/session/abstra
    ct/id.rb:220:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375709+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375698+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375702+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_reco
    rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375704+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375707+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375711+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375716+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375700+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_reco
    rd/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375721+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375726+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375705+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375720+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375729+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375738+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375718+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375723+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logg
    er.rb:38:in `call_app'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375725+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logg
    er.rb:20:in `block in call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375741+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:11
    3:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375736+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:
    in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375728+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_sup
    port/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride
    .rb:22:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375753+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `ru
    n'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375731+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logg
    er.rb:20:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375732+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375739+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispat
    ch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375746+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in
    `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375756+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375758+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375743+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb
    :518:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375748+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/content_length
    .rb:15:in `call'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375750+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webric
    k.rb:89:in `service'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375751+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `s
    ervice'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375755+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block
     in start_thread'
    ←[36m2015-04-04T03:28:59.375745+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/applicati
    on.rb:164:in `call'
```

What can I do here? I see nothing in the logs that can help me diagnose a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has something to do with sending an email most likely the email confirmation.

Do you have it setup to use some SMTP server to send the emails? If so try overriding the send email settings to use a third party api like sedgrid or mailgun.

app/mailers/spree/order_mailer_decorator.rb

```
Spree::OrderMailer.class_eval do

  def confirm_email(order, resend = false)
    @order = order.respond_to?(:id) ? order : Spree::Order.find(order)
    subject = (resend ? "[#{Spree.t(:resend).upcase}] " : '')
    subject += "#{Spree::Store.current.name} #{Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.subject')} ##{@order.number}"
    # mail(to: @order.email, from: from_address, subject: subject)
    puts "=================="
    puts "=================="
    puts "=====#{@order.email}====="
    puts "=================="
    puts "=================="
    sendgrid = SendGrid::Client.new(api_user: 'myuser', api_key: 'mypassword')
    mail = SendGrid::Mail.new do |m|
      m.to = @order.email
      m.from = 'me@me.com'
      m.subject = subject
      html_body = render_to_string("spree/mailers/confirm_email", :layout => "spree/layouts/base_email")
      m.html = html_body.to_str
    end
    puts sendgrid.send(mail)
  end

end
```